# Accessing a File in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

everyone.
I want to access a .wav file from my Assets folder in a UWP app,
as follow:

```
StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"ms-appx:///Assets/"+"sound.wav");
```

but I get the following error:

```
UWP accessing file System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.
```

I though I did everything right as described in MSDN, but I get the error still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/"+"sound.wav"));
```

or

```
StorageFile file = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\"+"sound.wav");
```